# Duplicate persistence units with name *PU

Tags: java, maven, persistence, weblogic, jdeveloper

I'm trying to install a WAR file generated by Maven to a Weblogic server, but I get the following error messages from weblogic while trying to deploy:

```
Duplicate persistence units with name DummyPU. 
First PU location: 
file:/home/weblogic/middleware/user_projects/domains/middleware_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/ichipscreens/l4qn3z/lib/jps-internal.jar. 

Second PU location:
 file:/home/weblogic/middleware/user_projects/domains/middleware_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/ichipscreens/wo22a/war/WEB-INF/lib/jps-internal.jar
```

What does this mean? and how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

In your Maven packaging step, it's putting the same module (jps-internal.jar) with the same persistence-unit defined, into two different locations within the application being deployed. When you deploy it, Weblogic says it's an error.

Make sure you only have one jps-internal.jar in your war file.

Answer (score 0):

please check you java Build Path in your properties.Probably you are selecting from root(src) ,which is wrong.Build path should be in following loc:-
/src/main/java & /src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue. 
However the cause of the issue is different.
In my ear file's application.xml, I have `<library-directory>jars-dir</library-directory>` element.I have commented it out since there's no ear jars needed by my application. 
It worked !